# Why isn't the @Deprecated annotation triggering a compiler warning about a method?

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to use the [@Deprecated annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html). The @Deprecated documentation says that: "Compilers warn when a deprecated program element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code". I would think this should trigger it, but it did not. javac version 1.7.0_09 and compiled using and not using -Xlint and 
-deprecation.

```
public class TestAnnotations {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      TestAnnotations theApp = new TestAnnotations();
      theApp.thisIsDeprecated();
   }

   @Deprecated
   public void thisIsDeprecated()
   {
      System.out.println("doing it the old way");
   }
}
```

Edit: per the comment of gd1 below regarding it only working if the method is in another class, I added a second class. And it DOES WARN on the call to theOldWay():

```
public class TestAnnotations {

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      TestAnnotations theApp = new TestAnnotations();
      theApp.thisIsDeprecated();
      OtherClass thatClass = new OtherClass();
      thatClass.theOldWay();
   }

   @Deprecated
   public void thisIsDeprecated()
   {
      System.out.println("doing it the old way");
   }
}

class OtherClass {

   @Deprecated
   void theOldWay()
   {
      System.out.println("gone out of style");
   }


}
```

The warning:

> /home/java/TestAnnotations.java:10: warning: [deprecation]
>   theOldWay() in OtherClass has been deprecated
>
> ```
>     thatClass.theOldWay();
>              ^
> ```
>
> 1 warning

Comment: WARNING: I'm just guessing. Maybe no deprecated warning is fired unless you call the deprecated method from another class. Random guess.

Comment: @gd1 no. Deprecation Doesn't trigger warning. You have to manage Deprecation logic in your framework/application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.3.6):

> A Java compiler must produce a deprecation warning when a type,
>   method, field, or constructor whose declaration is annotated with the
>   annotation @Deprecated is used (i.e. overridden, invoked, or
>   referenced by name), unless:
>
> - The use is within an entity that is itself annotated with the annotation @Deprecated; or
> - The use is within an entity that is annotated to suppress the warning with the annotation @SuppressWarnings("deprecation"); or
> - The use and declaration are both within the same outermost class.

Your example is an example of the last condition: you're only using the deprecated method from the same outermost class as the deprecated method.

Comment: Thanks. I think they should add that information to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecation Doesn't always trigger warnings. You have to manage Deprecation logic in your framework/application.

From [1.5 JavaDoc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html)

> NOTE: The Java Language Specification requires compilers to issue warnings when classes, methods, or fields marked with the @Deprecated annotation are used. Compilers are not required by the Java Language Specification to issue warnings when classes, methods, or fields marked with the @deprecated Javadoc tag are accessed, although the Sun compilers currently do so. However, there is no guarantee that the Sun compiler will always issue such warnings.

Comment: The text you quoted contradicts your answer: *The Java Language Specification requires compilers to issue warnings when classes, methods, or fields marked with the @Deprecated annotation are used*. So the compiler is *required* to trigger a warning.

Comment: "..However, there is no guarantee that the Sun compiler will always issue such warnings.."

Comment: the optional warnings are on the deprecated **javadoc tag**, not on the Deprecated **Java annotation**.